# Exchange 2003. Find all mailboxes a particular user has read permissions on

Tags: permissions, exchange-2003, mailbox

What would be the easiest way to find all mailboxes a particular user has read permissions on. I know it's possible via scripting but I want to know if there is a more convenient way.

Any tools out there that can give me that result?